# Como criar tags internas no Site. Ex: HOME FAQ CONTACT etc

Tags: html

Sou novo no grupo overflow e também em HTML. Ja tenho os conhecimentos básicos de html mas gostaria de saber como criar tags internas no meu site que facilitem o usuario acessar o Home, FAQ, Contactos etc . Por exempo: HOME FAQ CONTACT ABOUT ME. mas em tabelinhas acessíveis. Agradecia pela resposta.

Comment: Deve ser mais específico e detalhar a pergunta. Veja: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Olá!
Não sei ao certo se percebi a sua pergunta, mas creio que está a querer fazer uma barra de navegação. Se sim, a forma mais fácil é utilizar uma lista de itens:

```
<nav class="n1">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">HOME</a></li>
        <li class="ativo_h"><a href="#">FAQ</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">ABOUT ME</a></li>
      </ul>
</nav>
```

E depois formatar esta lista com CSS. Algo como:

```
    * {
      box-sizing:border-box;
    }

    nav{
      display: block;
      background-color: #eee;
      width: 100%;
    }

    a:link, a:active, a:visited{
      font-family: Arial;
      color: #000;
      text-decoration: none;
    }

    a:hover{
      background-color: #CC00FF;     
    }

    .ativo_h{
      background-color: rgb(153,255,102);
      border-bottom: 5px solid rgb(102,0,153);
    }

    .n1 ul {
        list-style-type: none;
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px;
        overflow: hidden;
    }

    .n1 li {
      float: left;  
    }

    .n1 li a {
      display: block;
      width: 100%;
      padding:20px;
    }
```

Obviamente, a formatação não tem que ser esta e pode ser feita de outras formas, em todo o caso, espero que ajude a responder à sua dúvida.

Comment: E isto mesmo que eu queria saber so que por ser novo nao sabia que a expressao correcta e "barra de navegacao"  mesmo assim estou grato.